# How do I 'cast' someting in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to React/Typescript. I have a function that takes a number and outputs a string, as such:

```
const getCurrentLevel = (wordCount: number): Level => {
  if (wordCount <= 3) {
    return 'Low';
  }

  if (wordCount <= 6) {
    return 'Med';
  }

  return 'High';
};
```

I then call this function below:

```
let helperLevel = getCurrentLevel(numWords);
```

And pass that to another component:

```
<helperText level={helperLevel} />
```

All this works fine, but I get a warning on compilation.

```
Cannot find name 'Level'.
```

On the line:

```
const getCurrentLevel = (wordCount: number): Level => {
```

I'm not sure what this means or now to fix it. As I understand, I must 'cast' this as "Level" as above. But I am not sure how to go about fixing this or what the error means.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think you're missing an `import { Level } '....';`

Comment: I don't understand sorry. Level isn't a comoponent.

Comment: i guest you need to define Level. type Level=string;

Answer (score 2):

```
type Level = 'Low' | 'Med' | 'High'
```

declare this line.

**Added**

`(wordCount: number): Level => { }` means it has one parameter as `number` type, it returns `Level` type. 
In your case, you return 'High', 'Low' and 'Med' you can declare like above that.

Comment: I have that declared on the `<helperText />`. Do I also need that in this file?

Comment: Sure, If you want to share the code, you can export the type and import that.

Comment: Thanks, I then get the problem `Type '{ level: Level; }' is missing the following properties from type 'HelperTextProps': lowLevel, medLevel, highLevel`